# $ H_n $ cardinal.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ n \in \mathbb N $ and define $ H_n = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z ^ 2 \mid | a | + | b | = n + 1 \} $.  Show that $ | H_n | = 4n + 4 $.

My attempt was to give a bijective function between $ H_n$ and $ J_ {4n + 4} $ where $J_n=\{1,2,3\ldots,n\}$ is the prototype of the finite sets, that is, if a set $ A $ is equipotent to $ J_n $, it is said that $ A $ is finite and $ | A | = n $.

The function is as follows: Let $\psi: H_n \to J_ {4n + 4}$ given by:

$$ \psi (a, b) = \begin {cases} b & \text {if } a \geq 0 \ \wedge \ b> 0 \\ | a | + n + 2 & \text {if } a <0 \ \wedge \ b> 0 \\ | a | + 2n + 4 & \text {if } a \leq 0 \ \wedge \ b <0 \\ b + 4n + 5 & \text {if } a> 0 \ \wedge \ b  <0 \\ n + 2 & \text {if } b = 0 \ \wedge \ a> 0 \\ 2n + 3 & \text {if } b = 0 \ \wedge \ a <0 \end {cases}$$

I would like to know if this function is bijective, and how to show that it is bijective.  To show that $ | H_n | = 4n + 4 $.

Comment: For which values of $n$ have you tested your conjecture?

Comment: The values ​​of $ n $ are those of the set $ J_ {4n + 4} = \{1,2,3, \ldots, n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, \ldots, 4n + 4 \} $.

Comment: That is not what your conjecture asserts, though, is it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are over-complicating this.  Try instead to reduce the problem to a simpler one.  If $(a,b)$ is a solution then so are $(\pm a, \pm b)$.  There is a complication in that the ambiguous sign makes no difference when $a$ or $b$ is $0$, so first we deal with that.

There are $3$ solutions when $a=0$ or $b= 0$, namely
$$(0,n+1),(0,-n-1),(n+1,0),(-n-1,0)$$

So now we know that the number of solutions is $4s+4$, where $s$ is the number of solutions in positive integers $a,b$.  These are of the form $(a, n+1-a)$ and in order that both entries are positive, $a$ can only take one the values $a=1,2,\dots, n$.